# use of undeclared identifier - cs50 problem set

Tags: c, cs50

I am new to programming in general and especially to c.
I am a bit confused as to why I get this error when trying to run the following code. It should be noted that I have some code before this but this is the part that is giving me some problems.
This is the part that seem to be giving me some problems:

```
#include <cs50.h>
#include <stdio.h>


    int a;

    do
    {
        int a = get_int("How many cents: ");
    }
    while(a < 0)
    return a;
```

The exact error message is:

```
Pset1/cash/ $ make cash
cash.c:44:13: error: declaration shadows a local variable [-Werror,-Wshadow]
        int a = get_int("How many cents: ");
            ^
cash.c:40:9: note: previous declaration is here
    int a;
        ^
fatal error: too many errors emitted, stopping now [-ferror-limit=]
2 errors generated.
make: *** [<builtin>: cash] Error 1
```

Comment: Change `int a =` to just `a =`. You're creating a local variable inside the `do` loop, not assigning the outer variable.

Comment: You have two `int a;` declarations which means they are two seperate variables. The compiler is telling you that the second one is hiding the first one and is likely not what you intended. See previous comment for fix.

Comment: Research tip: Next time you have an error just enter it directly into your favourite search engine. That will get you an answer most of the time without having to post a new question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the error message states, you defined a variable named `a` inside of the loop that shadows the definition of a variable with the same name at a higher scope.

Don't create a new variable.  Just assign to the one you have.

```
a = get_int("How many cents: ");
```

Comment: is that because I have already stated the datatype of the variable above?

Comment: @AntónioRebelo Stating the datatype is what defines a new variable.